# Using invoke-command from C# throwing exception

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command, executionpolicy

I have tried the following case from powershell terminal :

```
invoke-command -connectionuri "http://FullMachineName/wsman" -configuration "http
://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell" -credential "MachineName\Administrator" -filepath "C:\scripts\get
Users.ps1"
```

This is working fine.
But when I am trying the same thing through invoke command from C# it is throwing the following exception :

```
System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException was unhandled
  Message=File C:\scripts\getUsers.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
  Source=System.Management.Automation
  WasThrownFromThrowStatement=false
  StackTrace:
       at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
       at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
       at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
  InnerException: System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException
       Message=File C:\scripts\getUsers.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
       Source=System.Management.Automation
       WasThrownFromThrowStatement=false
       StackTrace:
            at System.Management.Automation.AuthorizationManager.ShouldRunInternal(CommandInfo commandInfo, CommandOrigin origin, PSHost host)
            at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSExecutionCmdlet.GetScriptBlockFromFile(String filePath)
            at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSExecutionCmdlet.BeginProcessing()
            at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand.BeginProcessing()
            at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing()
            at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin()
       InnerException: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
            Message=File C:\scripts\getUsers.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
            InnerException:
```

I am trying with the following code :

```
String file = @"C:\scripts\getUsers.ps1";
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()
PSCommand cmd = new PSCommand();                
cmd.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
cmd.AddParameter("CONNECTIONURI", "http://FullMachineName/wsman");
cmd.AddParameter("FILEPATH",file);
cmd.AddParameter("CREDENTIAL", Credential);            
cmd.AddParameter("CONFIGURATION","http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell" );
ps.Commands = cmd;                
Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runSpace.Open();
ps.Runspace = runSpace;
psObjects = ps.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 3):

The typical problem in this scenario is that you have run Set-ExecutionPolicy in PowerShell for either the 32-bit or the 64-bit version of PowerShell but not both.  The C# program you are running is likely the bit-ness where you haven't changed PowerShell's default execution policy.  Try opening up both a 32-bit and a 64-bit PowerShell session and ensure the execution policy is set to RemoteSigned or Unrestricted.

Comment: Tried with execution policy RemoteSigned and Unrestricted from 32 bit windows powershell.Still getting the same error.

Comment: Try compiling the app as x86.

Comment: I tried the invoke-command directly in a powershell 32 bit terminal and I am getting the exception mentioned in the question.

Comment: And if you run Get-ExecutionPolicy in that shell, does it return `Restricted`? If so, you need to run (in an elevated 32-bit PowerShell) `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting and Getting Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted using PowerShell Instance.

```
 public static ICollection<PSObject> RunScriptText(string scriptFullPath, ICollection<CommandParameter> parameters = null)
        {
            var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                var initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
                Console.WriteLine("Importing ServerManager module");
                initial.ImportPSModule(new[] { "ServerManager" });

                PowerShellInstance.Runspace = runspace;

                PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-ExecutionPolicy");
                PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

                var cmd = new Command(scriptFullPath);
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (var p in parameters)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                    }
                }
                pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
                var results = pipeline.Invoke();
                pipeline.Dispose();
                runspace.Dispose();
                return results;
            }
            return null;
        }
```